# removing all white margins from plt.show() when trying do show an image

Tags: matplotlib, plot, pycharm, margins, imshow

hello i'm trying to load an image and display it without having any margins
I could not find any solution to this and would appreciate assistance

### code:

from matplotlib.image import imread

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = 'some legal image path'

im = imread(path)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=plt.figaspect(im))

plt.axis('off')

fig.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1)

ax.imshow(im)

plt.show()

this still produces margins
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rka0K.png)

Comment: This shouldn't happen, when I run your code it will [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACkvM.png). So there is a tiny little space on *one side* of the image, due to the window resizing the figure, but it should not occur on both sides. Which backend are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure which backend pycharm runs on

Comment: I added the pycharm tag. I don't know what's going on, but someone familiar with pycharm may have an idea.